# Custom Fields displaying in single line

Tags: custom-field, line-breaks

I have custom fields to display in a post.  But all of the custom fields are displaying in a single continuous line, while i want them in separate lines. I am not a coder. I tried `<br>, <li>` but still no luck. I also searched in stack exchange and web for similar problem, but could not get answer. Please help.

Below is the Code i have in single.php after -  `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$key_name = get_post_custom_values ($key = 'country'); echo 'Country : ', $key_name[0];
$key_name = get_post_custom_values ($key = 'status'); echo 'Status : ', $key_name[0];`

The result in the post is as below:

Country : Saudi ArabiaStatus : Announced

I want it to appear it like the one below:

Country : Saudi Arabia

Status : Announced

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, but why don't you try the following:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div><?php $key_name = get_post_custom_values ($key = 'country'); echo 'Country : ', $key_name[0]; ?> </div>
<div><?php $key_name = get_post_custom_values ($key = 'status'); echo 'Status : ', $key_name[0]; ?> </div>
```

Comment: I tried <div> and get this message - "There has been a critical error on your website.
Learn more about debugging in WordPress."

Comment: Please, make sure that you entered php mode again after the last closing div:
        <?php
Hope that helps!

Comment: added  <?php after the last closing div.  Still i get debugging error as told above.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on the answer provided by user4379653 here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636676/php-line-break-not-working

I used `<br />` in echo from the second custom field, as the first field would not require.

`$key_name = get_post_custom_values ($key = 'status'); echo '<br />Status : ', $key_name[0];`

Thanks to Ivo for trying to help.